# Make a div expand to right?

Tags: javascript, css, html

Is there any way to make a div expand to right with css when content added to it with ajax? Or should i use javascript for this job?

Also parent container has a width set, but also has overflow:auto. Sorry for late edit

Comment: If you don't set a width for a DIV, it will always expand to the width available in the parent container. If you have set a width, you will need to edit that via JavaScript.

Comment: but parent has a width set, i need the div to expand while parent stays still with a scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using JS to retrieve/add content via AJAX, you could have the JS code add/modify the class on the `<div>` as well.  Then you can control it with CSS.

Comment: yes but there must be a way to obtain this without javascript, the page has nearly 1000 lines of javascript and i don't want to add more :D

Comment: I'm just saying that in your function which is already populating the div, just add a line to add or modify the CSS class of the div. One line of JS will solve your problem and give you control via CSS... so what's nearly 1001 lines of JS ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mydiv").animate({
    width += 'xxx'
},5000);
```

You may want your width value to scale with the length of your response. Perhaps create a multiplier.